# Getting Windows Task Scheduler to show Failure for "Run Result"

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, executable

I've created an executable file from a c# program, in which the main method returns an integer value - 0 for success and 1 for failure.

I have a Windows Task Scheduler task which runs this executable file. However, no matter what the main method returns, the Task Scheduler will always display "Success" for this task, simply because the console window closed.

I have also tried creating a batch file to run the executable, and having the Task Scheduler run the batch file instead. The batch file looks like this:

```
start /d "c:\filepath" file.exe
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Currently this seems to have no effect on the Task Scheduler. How can I get the Task Scheduler to show that the task failed?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify an exit code other than the default value of 0 (which means success). You can do this using

```
Environment.Exit(someNumber)
```

[For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16969704)

Comment: You mean from within the c# code, right? I tried that, and didn't see any difference. Task Scheduler still said Success.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/330751/how-to-make-taskscheduler-fail-when-the-task-returns-result-different-from-0

Comment: Yeah, I did see that. My client specifically wants the Task Scheduler to show a failure, so I was hoping someone would have an idea of how to trick it into doing so.