# Windows Task Scheduler reports incorrect/inconsistent result code

Tags: windows, azure, scheduled-tasks, exit-code, errorlevel

**Background:** I am attempting to get email notification upon failure of a scheduled task. My task can indicate failure via exit code (errorlevel) and I want to use that and follow the filter approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289360/29805) to trigger an email.

**Problem:** I am getting inconsistent behavior from Task Scheduler on different machines and versions of Windows. To test, I'm using the following very simple task.

- Run only when user is logged on. (where "user" is the current user)
- Action: Start a program

  - Program/script: `cmd`
  - Arguments: `/c "exit /b 1"`
  - Start in: blank
- Everything else: default

I've enabled Task History, and when I manually run the task on both Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, a correct history item like the following is created in category "Action completed":

> Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\test" , instance "{abcdefgh-fab0-4a21-b51a-e25baaaa0000}" , action "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.EXE" with return code 1.

The text in the *Last Run Result* column corresponds to this: `(0x1)`.

However, when run on Windows Server 2012 (Azure VM), the following erroneous message appears:

> Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\test" , instance "{abcdefgh-fab0-4a21-b51a-e25bbbbb1111}" , action "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.EXE" **with return code 0**.

(Emphasis mine.) However the text in the *Last Run Result* column reads: `Incorrect function: (0x80070001)`. This indicates that at least part of the Task Scheduling processor recognizes some degree of error condition. If I replace the arguments with `/c "exit /b 0"`, this column reads: `The operation completed successfully. (0x0)`

I've tried various combinations of values for user context, "start in" directory, arguments (with and without `/b`), and different operating systems under "Configure for:", to no avail.

**Question:** How can I get Task Scheduler on the Windows 2012 machine to display the correct return code in the history item?

**Workaround:** While I still want to understand this bizarre behavior (perhaps it indicates some more significant problem/misunderstanding), I am solving my original issue by adding the following to my task script:

```
$objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$objMailMessage.From = "username@gmail.com"
$objMailMessage.To.Add("recipient@example.com")
$objMailMessage.Subject = "The task failed."
#$objMailMessage.Body = "Detailed information."

$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
$smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$smtp.Credentials = new-object Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com","pass")
$smtp.send($objMailMessage)
```

Comment: Same issue reported here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150922/return-code-of-scheduled-task-prefixed-with-0x8007000-in-list-view-registered-a/22186914#22186914). I researched this but found no other mentions.

Comment: Solution is simple: don't expect that Task Scheduler works as intended. Period. The expected behavior from M$ software is that it doesn't work and nobody explains why. I have sucked a lot with Task Scheduler, too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing a similar issue on Server 2012 with a batch file that looks like it succeeds, shows a return value of 0 in event log, but a Last Run Result of 0x80070001.

I see MSFT has a hotfix available for Server 2012 which might address this issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3003689

Comment: Awesome, I'll give the hotfix a whirl! Hopefully the Azure VMs automatically received this.