# C# Console App Exit Code with Task Scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a C# Console application that runs under Windows Task Scheduler.

Should the application fail for what ever reason, I use "Exit Codes" to propagate back to Task Scheduler.

However, no matter what I try, Task Schedule logs always report "Task Completed Successfully".

I have tried the two defined exit strategies.. being...

```
Environment.Exit(hasError ? -1 : 0);
```

and

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    ... code ...
   return (hasError ? -1 : 0);
}
```

Any suggestions what I may be doing wrong

Running app in Windows Server 2012 Standard

Comment: The answer to your question can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969500/how-do-i-notify-windows-task-scheduler-when-my-application-fails

Comment: If did read the one bill but the bit where it say **Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\test4" , instance "{a41adae0-a378-45f6-aadc-648d27852042}" , action "C:\blah..blah\Release\WpfApplication1.exe" with return code 55.** always says **with return code 0**

Comment: Did you verify that your code `(hasError ? -1 : 0)` isn't returning 0 even though you may be expecting -1 ?

Comment: I've put test code in to just `return (64)` and it still says **with return code 0**

Comment: instead of `return(64)` try doing `Environment.Exit(64)` directly? Do you get the same return code when running the app manually?

Comment: I just created a brand new console application and put `Environment.Exit(45)` as the only line of code and added it to Task scheduler, and I received the correct history with the correct return code.

Comment: Same problem. **return code 0**

Comment: What O/S you running?

Comment: Server 2008, don't have a 2012 to test

Comment: also... can you advise where the error code is visible... just in case i am looking in the wrong place

Comment: Join this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80297/so-30783682

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/o515OOW.png is a screenshot. I'll assist you in the chat link Black Frog shared if you want further help

Comment: @bill I can see in your screen shot that it shows the 45 exit code but mine ALWAYS says 0 no matter what exit code I specify

Comment: Create a brand new Console application and just put Environment.Exit(45); and then make that a scheduled task. If that doesn't work, then there is an issue with your server.

Comment: Will try that next week bill... (Tuesday!)

Comment: Right... Done the test.... Two lines of code ... `File.WriteAllText("text.txt","Just Checking");` ... `Environment.Exit(45);` resulting in a text file being created and the following in the Task Scheduler "History" tab

`Task Scheduler successfully completed task "xxxxxxxxxxx" , instance "{d18ea25c-2d1d-43d0-9485-8005776df35f}" , action "xxxxxx.exe" with return code 0.`

Comment: Tried the same programme on a Win 2003 server and it worked... Task Completion Status: 45.... So... Looks like a Win 2012 error then,,

Comment: OK... Interestingly the Last Run Result was "0x8007002D" === 2D = 45

But Eventlog says "0"...

Comment: Seems I have a possible answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150922/return-code-of-scheduled-task-prefixed-with-0x8007000-in-list-view-registered-a

Comment: Well... it now shows "45" on both items...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its a Windows 2012 Server issue and requires the following hot-fix

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3003689