# Restart on unhandled exception task scheduler

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, unhandled-exception

How can i set the task to restart automatically when an unhandled exception occurs? I have tried the setting "If the task fails, retart every:" but it doesnt restart the task.

Comment: Please show your code that is relevant to the problem

Comment: Lets just say that my application just throws an exception without a catch simulating an unhandled exception.

Comment: just to be clear, are you referring to the .NET type `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`?

Comment: I suppose the question is about restarting an application (*.exe file) that was started by Windows Task Scheduler and finished because of uncaught exception. Have you found the solution?

Comment: I suppose the following answer could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335551/how-does-windows-task-scheduler-in-win7-recognize-a-failed-task#answer-10282877